# NodeJS ExpressJS PassportJS - for Admin Pages Only

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

Im using NodeJS, ExpressJS, Mongoose, passportJS & connect-ensure-login. Authenticating users works perfectly.

```
....
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
  , ensureLoggedIn = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn;

var app = express();
...
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());    
...


passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password'},
    function(email, password, done) {
  User.findOne({ 'email': email, 'password': password },
               {'_id': 1, 'email':1}, function(err, user) {

    if (err) { return done(err); }

    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
    }

    return done(null, user);
  });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {  
  done(null, user);
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local',
    { successReturnToOrRedirect: '/home', failureRedirect: '/login' }));

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Now, I want to add restrictions to some routes to be accessible only by admin. How can I do that? e.g. `/admin/*`

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});

mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

Any hint? Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could attach a custom middleware to the `/admin/*` route that would check for admin status before passing the request on the any of the more specific `/admin/` routes:

```
var ensureLoggedIn = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn;
...
var requiresAdmin = function() {
  return [
    ensureLoggedIn('/login'),
    function(req, res, next) {
      if (req.user && req.user.isAdmin === true)
        next();
      else
        res.send(401, 'Unauthorized');
    }
  ]
};

app.all('/admin/*', requiresAdmin());
app.get('/admin/', ...);
```

Comment: I added your solution, but I think I missed something, it's always Unauthorized.

Comment: @JRGalia you are quite correct, I edited my answer to fix that mistake :)

Comment: @robertklep This solution will work if we need to authenticate only admin user, what if we want to login from both admin and user at the same time, *req.user* will already have admin user. When we will try to authenticate with normal user,how do we deal with that. Is there any way to set *req.admin* after authenticating admin user and set *req.user* after authenticating normal user.

Comment: @HamzaKhan being an admin is typically a property that can be assigned to any user, and that's also what this code depends on (`isAdmin` is stored in the database, and is set to `true` for any user that has admin privileges). Passport doesn't support multiple concurrently logged in users. If you mean you want to be able to log in as a regular user and as an admin inside the same browser, consider using incognito/private browsing mode for one user, and regular browsing mode for the other user.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks for your answer, that is exactly what i wanted to know. I have now used req.session.user and req.session.admin to keep both type of users logged in at the same time, please tell me that is this a bad approach or we can live with that.

Comment: @HamzaKhan I don't think that will work properly. For instance, what would happen if that user changes their password? Will the password of `req.session.user` be changed, or from `req.session.admin`? I would either make the "admin" property a part of your user model (so you can assign a user to _also_ be an admin), or use my incognito/private browsing tip to log in as two separate users.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Add following function to your app.js above **app.use(app.router)** call;

//This function will be called every time when the server receive request.

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated || req.isAuthenticated())
  {
    var currentUrl = req.originalUrl || req.url;
    //Check wheather req.user has access to the above URL
    //If req.user don't have access then redirect the user
    // to home page or login page
    res.redirect('HOME PAGE URL');
  }
  next();
});
```

I have not tried it but i think it will work.

Comment: should be `if (req.isAuthenticated())`